# How to fetch data from website using API

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5

I have never used API  before and this is the first work that I am going to use API to fetch data from another website to my website. Is there is any such API through which i can fetch data with PHP or Laravel5 etc.?

Actually i need to extract exchange rates from http://www.nrb.org.np/fxmexchangerate.php to my website. I should get the recent data i.e. updated data from this website.

How can i do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: The webpage doesn't offer any api, you have to write your own. Get the content of the page and use reg exp to fetch the data. It's not that difficult.

Answer (score 4):

> API: application program interface.

If the site you're trying to collect data from doesn't provide an API then you'd have to find a way to collect the data yourself. If you're using PHP you can check [this parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for a simple HTML DOM extractor.

They provide various examples on their site, check these and also check the structure of the site you're trying to get the content from and you should be fine:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
   echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
   echo $element->href . '<br>';
```